# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fulfilled') in createAsyncThunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

Im using createasyncthunk for creating async action to dispatch async action with redux toolkit , im having all the async api functions in seperate file ,ive imported into my createslice and used in extrareducers.

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { DataService } from 'config.axios'
import { getItem } from 'utils/localStorageController'
import { activateAlert } from 'reduxStore/slices/alert/AlertSlice'
import { clearRuleData } from '../RuleDataSlice'

const study_id = getItem('study_id')

export const getEditCheckByStatus = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/getEditCheck',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        let editCheckType = params?.type ? `/${params.type}` : ''
        let searchParams = params?.search ? `&search=${params.search}` : ''
        let page = params?.page ? `&page=${params.page}` : ''
        let per_page = params?.per_page ? `&per_page=${params.per_page}` : ''
        let sortField = params?.sortField ? `&sort_field=${params.sortField}` : ''
        let sortOrder = params?.sortOrder ? `&order=${params.sortOrder}` : ''

        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.get(
                `/edit-checks${editCheckType}?status=${params.status}&study_id=${study_id}${searchParams}${page}${per_page}${sortField}${sortOrder}`
            )
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Get EC by status error:', error)
        }
    }
)

export const getEditCheckCount = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/getEditCheckCount',
    async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.get(`/edit-checks/count`)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Get EC Count error:', error)
        }
    }
)

export const getEditCheckWithFilter = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/getEditCheckWithFilter',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        let page = params?.page ? `&page=${params.page}` : ''
        let per_page = params?.per_page ? `&per_page=${params.per_page}` : ''
        let searchParams = params?.search ? `&search=${params.search}` : ''
        let sortField = params?.sortField ? `&sort_field=${params.sortField}` : ''
        let sortOrder = params?.sortOrder ? `&order=${params.sortOrder}` : ''
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.get(
                `/edit-checks/status/${params.inAction}?worked_for=${params.forAction}${searchParams}${page}${per_page}${sortField}${sortOrder}`
            )
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Get Edit Checks with Filter error:', error)
        }
    }
)

export const updateWorkflow = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/updateworkflow',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            await DataService.put(
                `/edit-checks/${params.id}/workflow/${params.action}`,
                params.api_body
            )
            thunkAPI.dispatch(
                activateAlert({ color: 'success', content: params.content })
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Update workflow error:', error)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(activateAlert({ color: 'danger', content: error }))
        }
    }
)

export const deleteEditCheck = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/deleteEditCheck',
    async (id, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            await DataService.delete(`/edit-checks/${id}/`)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(
                activateAlert({
                    color: 'success',
                    content: 'Edit Check Deleted Succesfully',
                })
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Delete EditCheck error:', error)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(activateAlert({ color: 'danger', content: error }))
        }
    }
)

export const getEditCheckById = createAsyncThunk(
    'ruledata/getEditCheckById',
    async (id, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.get(`/edit-checks/${id}/`)
            return data.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Get Edit Check with ID error:', error)
        }
    }
)

export const createRuleData = createAsyncThunk(
    'ruledata/createrule',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.post(`/edit-checks/`, params.api_body)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(
                activateAlert({
                    color: 'success',
                    content: 'New Rule Request Created Succesfully',
                })
            )
            thunkAPI.dispatch(clearRuleData())
            if (params.send_for_development) {
                thunkAPI.dispatch(
                    updateWorkflow({
                        api_body: {
                            status: 'DEVELOPMENT',
                            comments: 'Please develop the code',
                        },
                        id: data.data.id,
                        content: 'EC Sent to Development',
                        action: '',
                    })
                )
            }
            return data.data.id
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Create Rule data error:', error)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(activateAlert({ color: 'danger', content: error }))
        }
    }
)

export const updateRuleDataForm = createAsyncThunk(
    'ruledata/updaterule',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.put(
                `/edit-checks/${params.api_body?.id}`,
                params.api_body
            )
            thunkAPI.dispatch(
                activateAlert({
                    color: 'success',
                    content: 'Edit Check Updated Succesfully',
                })
            )
            thunkAPI.dispatch(clearRuleData())
            if (params?.send_for_development) {
                thunkAPI.dispatch(
                    updateWorkflow({
                        api_body: {
                            status: 'DEVELOPMENT',
                            comments: 'Please develop the code',
                        },
                        id: data.data.id,
                        content: 'EC Sent to Development',
                        action: '',
                    })
                )
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Update rule data form error:', error)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(activateAlert({ color: 'danger', content: error }))
        }
    }
)

export const getECDomains = createAsyncThunk('ruledata/getdomain', async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await DataService.get(`/studies/1/domains/`)
        return data.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Get domain error', error)
    }
})

export const getECDomainCols = createAsyncThunk(
    'ruledata/getdomaincols',
    async (domain, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await DataService.get(
                `/studies/1/domains/${domain}/variables`
            )
            let cols = data.data.map(function (el) {
                return el.name
            })
            let cols_data = cols.map((col) => ({ label: col, value: col }))

            console.log(cols, cols_data, 'action cols')
            return  {domain , cols: cols_data }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Get Edit Check domain columns error:',error)
        }
    }
)

export const saveCodeScript = createAsyncThunk(
    'editchecks/savecodescript',
    async (params, thunkAPI) => {
        const codeData = new FormData()
        codeData.append('source_code', params.code)
        try {
            await DataService.post(
                `/edit-checks/${params.id}/script/?study_id=75`,
                codeData,
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Save script error: ', error)
        }
    }
)

The below file is src/reduxStore/slices/edit-checks/services/editCheckthunk.js
```

This is in different file.

```
import { createSlice, createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { push } from 'connected-react-router'
import {
    createRuleData,
    updateRuleDataForm,
    getECDomains,
    getECDomainCols,
    getEditCheckById,
} from './services/editCheckthunk'

const initialState = {
    ruleData: {
        name: '',
        source_data_format: '',
        severity: '',
        processing_level: '',
        description: '',
        query_text: '',
        dataset: {
            primary: {
                domain: '',
                columns: [],
            },
            relational: {
                domain: '',
                columns: [],
            },
        },
    },
    // from the api
    dataset_data: {
        domains: [],
        domain_cols: {},
    },
    ruleDataLoader: false,
}

export const clearRuleData = createAction(
    'ruledata/clearformdata',
    function prepare() {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(push('/edit-checks/new'))
        }
    }
)

const ruleDataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ruledata',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateRuleData(state, action) {
            const { key, value } = action.payload
            state.ruleData[key] = value
        },
        updateDataset(state, action) {
            const { key_1, key_2, value } = action.payload
            state.ruleData.dataset[key_1] = {
                ...state.ruleData.dataset[key_1],
                [key_2]: value,
            }
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [clearRuleData]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleData = initialState.ruleData
        },
        [getEditCheckById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleData = action.payload
        },
        [createRuleData.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = true
        },
        [createRuleData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = false
            state.ruleData.id = action.payload
        },
        [createRuleData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = false
        },
        [updateRuleDataForm.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = false
        },
        [updateRuleDataForm.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = false
            state.ruleData.id = action.payload
        },
        [updateRuleDataForm.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.ruleDataLoader = false
        },
        [getECDomains.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.dataset_data.domains = action.payload
        },
        [getECDomainCols.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            const { domain, cols } = action.payload
            state.dataset_data.domain_cols = {
                ...state.dataset_data.domain_cols,
                [domain]: cols,
            }
        },
    },
})

export const { updateDataset, updateRuleData } = ruleDataSlice.actions
export default ruleDataSlice.reducer
```

These are my other reducers with createasyncthunk functions.

Im dispatching , say `getEditCheckById` action in component to call the API.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router'
import Select from 'react-select'

import { updateRuleDataForm,createRuleData,getECDomains,getECDomainCols,getEditCheckById } from 'reduxStore/slices/edit-checks/services/editCheckthunk';
import { updateRuleData ,clearRuleData, updateDataset} from 'reduxStore/slices/edit-checks/RuleDataSlice';
import chevronLeftIcon from 'assets/img/icons/utils/fi_chevron-left.svg'

function CreateEditCheck(props) {
    const { search,pathname } = useLocation()
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search)
    const editCheckId = searchParams.get('id')
    const isEditParam = searchParams.get('edit')
  
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(isEditParam === 'true' || isEditParam === null ? true : false)
  const {ruleData , dataset_data} = useSelector((state) => state.editChecks.ruledata)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const action = pathname.split('/')[2]
    const history = useHistory()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (action === 'edit') {
      dispatch(getEditCheckById(editCheckId))
        }
        dispatch(getECDomains())
    }, [])
}
```

But im getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fulfilled')` while running the app. THank in advance

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the error is caused by from accessing `fulfilled` of `getEditCheckById`? Could you try printing all the imported thunk actions, says, before `const ruleDataSlice = createSlice({` to see if which ones are undefined?

Comment: @asinkxcoswt , you mean console log the imported thunk actions as string?

Comment: @Ashiq yes, exactly.

Comment: Hey @asinkxcoswt  , as you said ,ive console logged the thunk action `geteditcheckbyid` , console.log('thunk actions',getEditCheckById.toString());,before slice initialization , but its not logged in the console

Comment: yes its not exported properly i think , can i have async function inside the slices

Comment: @Ashiq, so you find which ones are actually undefined, right? Could you show me how you export that module, maybe I can help you see why the export does not work. As far as I can see, I don't see any wrong with `export const getEditCheckById = createAsyncThunk( ... )`, the `createAsyncThunk` should not return `undefined`. Oh and I mean not only the `getEditCheckById`, but everything from your `./services/editCheckthunk` could potentially be the culprit.

Comment: Hey @asinkxcoswt, thank you for sticking with me , ive udpated the src/reduxStore/slices/edit-checks/services/editCheckthunk.js file , please have a look

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find anything wrong. But maybe it worth trying comment out or removing all the `extraReducers` of the `ruleDataSlice` to see if the error still persists, if so it can mean we are looking in the wrong file from the start.

Comment: i too , i declared the thunk functions throwing error inside the slice function itself, its workinf fine now , may be too many exports?